# Assert after batch job is executed

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

below test method is failing at

> system.assert "Expecting 10, actual 0"

But `system.debug on "total"` in the finish of batch class has value 10.

**Batch class**

```
        public class CountRecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
            public Integer total = 0;

            public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
                return Database.getQueryLocator('select id from contact');
            }

            public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
                total += scope.size();
            }

            public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
                 system.debug('hello'+total);
            }
        }
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
static void testBatch(){
    Integer count = 10;
    List<Contact> conList = createConList(count); //creates 10 contacts
    test.starttest();
    CountRecords cR = new CountRecords();
    Database.executeBatch(cR);
    test.stoptest();
    system.assertEquals(count, cR.total);
}
```

Comment: Batch run in Asynchronous mode. That's it is giving you error.

Comment: Thanks tushar.. but can you suggest if there is there anything else i can assert here ?

Comment: There is nothing logical happening except counting scope size. So, there cannot be any useful assert.

Comment: My bad.. this question is already answered by sfdcfox here : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15899/how-to-test-that-apex-batch-finish-sends-an-email

Comment: added a static variable and it is working now. :)

Comment: @pmvsdt  you can give ans to this question and close this question

Comment: @pmvsdt Thanks for the mention. Do feel free to answer the question.